# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^p}=\frac{n^{1-p}}{1-p}+\beta+O(\frac{1}{n^p}), (1＞p＞0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I noticed that $\frac{n^{1-p}}{1-p}=\int_0^n \frac{1}{x^p} dx$, and $\frac{1}{x^p}$ is monotonous decreasing, which means $\frac{1}{k^p} \geq \int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x^p} dx$.

Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k^p} - \frac{n^p}{1-p}$ is increasing and$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^p} - \frac{n^p}{1-p}$ is decreasing.

I am stuck here. How can I get the $O(\frac{1}{n^p})$？